# How to replace character between two digits using re in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to work on a string dataset and replace '-' with a '.'
I have this dataset:

```
AUDI XXX-R 2-0TS
AUDI XXX-R 2-0T
AUDI X-R 2-0
```

I want the '-' to be replaced by '.' so all occurrences with number-number** should be replaced by number.number**

I have tried adding the following regex pattern but it replaces the Alphabet's '-' as-well

```
[^a-z-A-Z]?(\d)-(\d)?[a-zA-Z]?[a-z-A-Z]
```

I need the pattern where no matter what the string is the '-' between two digits should be replaced with '.'

Comment: Wouldn't just `(\d)-(\d)` work? Replace with `\1.\2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use [*lookaround* constructs [regular-expressions.info]](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
from re import compile as recompile

rgx = recompile(r'(?<=\d)[-](?=\d)')
```

for this `rgx`, we can then substitute like:

```
>>> rgx.sub('.', 'AUDI XXX-R 2-0TS AUDI XXX-R 2-0T AUDI X-R 2-0')
'AUDI XXX-R 2.0TS AUDI XXX-R 2.0T AUDI X-R 2.0'
```

If the digit on the right is optional, we can just omit it, like:

```
rgx = recompile(r'(?<=\d)[-]')
```

This will thus replace `3-A` with `3.A` as well.

Comment: @Williem Van Onsen everything is fine until this comes 2-5X Touring this remians untouched and im sad why.

Comment: @SaifAli: Both regexes return `'2.5X Touring'` for input `rgx.sub('.', '2-5X Touring')` locally.

Comment: okay thanks! but my dataset has now just one more thing 2-4 FORD XXX so i only want the '-' to be replaced if the digits have some preceding text.